# a href adds default URL with the given echo URL

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am a little stuck in one situation. I am removing some errors from my site and got one unexpected error
here below is my code:-

```
<?PHP
$release_web_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_links', true );
print_r($release_web_url) ; ?>
```

and the output of this code is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Website [url] =>www.google.com ) )
```

I only want to echo the array URL value in the anchor HTML tag. So I did this coding below:

```
foreach($release_web_url as $item): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $item['url']; ?>">Website</a>
<?php endforeach;
```

now instead of getting anchor link = [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) | I got anchor link = 192.168.1.50/jobifylocal/www.google.com |
that thing doesn't make any sense adding the other URL automatically in-front of the given URL.

Comment: If you look at the source code of the page, you'll see `<a href="www.google.com">`, the browser is showing you were that leads, it's not a WP bug, see Jacobs answer for why and how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve forgotten the `https://`. This will happen in any HTML where you don’t add the protocol to a URL. Nothing to do with WordPress.

However, you should use `esc_url()` when outputting user entered values into a link, to make sure the output is a valid URL, even if the user makes this same mistake:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item['url'] ); ?>">Website</a>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked